# How to disable liferay control panel for everyone (including administrator)?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, control-panel

Is there a way to remove the control panel in liferay completely through server-side settings? Because my users don't even want the admin to view the Admin button to access the control panel. Was thinking of removing the my account portlet in the liferay-portal.xml but it is still appearing for the adminstrator.

Answer (score 0):

Simple do not show the docbar on the page. The doc bar can be disabled by removing the following code in portal_normal.vm

```
<#if is_signed_in>
    <@liferay.dockbar />
</#if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple "visual" hiding may not be enough because you'll still be able to access the Control Panel through the direct link (/group/control_panel). 
So to disable it completely, take a closer look at the following method:

`com.liferay.portal.events.ServicePreAction.isViewableGroup() {
    ....
    if (group.isControlPanel()) { }
    ....
}`

Answer (score 0):

If they don't trust their administrator to make sensible use of the permissions that come with an administrator, why not just provide a user account with less permissions - e.g. not being able to access anything in controlpanel. Accessing to CP is a standard permission that you can grant or revoke to custom roles.

If you ever want to configure Liferay again, I'd advise to keep CP around.